# Deducting production costs from a total value

Tags: arithmetic

I have a rather rudimentary question regarding figuring out production costs for something. Let's say I am selling an Object for a retail value of `$10,000.00` and the person who I am getting it from paid `$2000.00` to produce it, of which only `$1000` needs to be reimbursed to him.

This is what i've used from before but someone is telling me the calculation is incorrect:

```
Cost:         $10,000.00
- Production: $1,000.00
Subtotal:     $9,000.00
Share 50%:    $4,500.00
+ Production: $1,000.00
Due Person A: $5,500.00
Due Person B: $4,500.00
```

The other calculation they are telling me to use is:

```
Cost:         $10,000.00
Share 50%:    $5,000.00
+ Production: $1,000.00
Due Person A: $6,000.00
Due Person B: $4,000.00
```

I feel like this is staring me squarely in the face but I am getting two different values and not sure which would be the correct calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 8000 profit, so each person should receive 4000 of it.  Whoever actually paid the 2000 should be reimbursed, then the remaining 8000 should be divided.  In your first calculation you only account for 1000 production cost.

Comment: sorry maybe I worded that incorrectly. We only have to pay 1000 of the production, not 2000.

Comment: Then the first calculation is correct.  It is the same idea.  Pay the 1000 to whoever spent it, then divide the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The first calculation is wrong because you are only sharing out half the cost of the production. The second calculation is correct.

Comment: Well the share is for only half the production. We need to pay them back 1000 from the profit

Comment: Ok so you changed the numbers

Comment: no i just worded it incorrectly. The person paid 2000 dollars, but he is paying 1000 from his own pocket and 1000 from ours. So his own pocket expense of 1000 is out of the picture.